# Android: Make sure file extension is always a csv when starting an Intent with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, savefiledialog

So when my Save Dialog activity is started it uses a default filename with the `.csv` extension; however, if a user changes the name and forgets the `.csv` extension it will save without one. I also noticed if the filename is the same as an existing file then the user needs to manually touch the old file to initiate an overwrite, and if they don't press the file then the current file will save without an extension instead of overwriting the file with the same name.

So there are two issues I don't want users to run into that come from using `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`:

1. users shouldn't need to manually touch a file with the same name to overwrite it, it should be automatic.
2. if the filename given by the user doesn't have a .csv extension is should be given one by default

In the code below I set the type to be a csv and generate a default filename. When the intent gives the user control they can accidently forget the `.csv` extension despite setting the type. Is there a way to solve these issues through settings in the Intent, or is there a better way to get around this issue?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/csv");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, device.getName()+"_data.csv");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CSV_FILE_CREATION);
```

Here I get the outputstream for the file:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CSV_FILE_CREATION) {
            try {
                Uri uri = intent.getData();
                OutputStream outStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
                // file writing stuff
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                Util.stackTrace(TAG, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `they can accidently forget the .csv extension ` You mean: they can accidently delete the .csv extension . You put it there. It is there. But the user can change file name and extension.

Comment: `and if they don't press the file then the current file will save without an extension.` No. It wil have the same name and extension but a number added like (#).

Comment: You cannot get what you want if you use ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT.

Comment: You could once let the user select a directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. After that handle all files to be created yourself.